# Replace a single word in HTML but NOT inside links

Tags: php, html

I have a piece of HTML and want to replace a particular word.

For example: `This is Test` -> `This is egegeg`

But I *don't* want to replace it inside links (`<a href=...`) and image links (`<img src=...`).

How can I solve this?

Comment: strpos and str_replace?

Comment: Please consider using punctuation and maybe some `formatting`. This question is currently nearly unreadable.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Comment: @DarylGill, no he wants to analyze html and parse for plain text in paragraps or similar - ignoring tags

Comment: i try this but this change my words in links to

Comment: Most likely you would like to parse the HTML at first to avoid unwanted substitutions...

Comment: @rubberboots Despite me suggesting such low-key solutions, if performed correctly.. This will do the job. DOM/HTML parsers and possible regular expressions (by *assumption*) might be out of OPs skillset currently

Comment: Someone suggested an [edit that removed key parts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6865012) of the question, and amazingly got it approved by three rookies. I have [unrolled and improved](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28176671/revisions) the question. **Note to @Supryk:** Inspect the changes to see if this is closer to what you meant. Please supply a better example of some HTML and explain what you want replaced and what you **don't** want replaced.

Answer (score -1):

To do this you would use `str_replace`:

```
$string = 'This is a test';
$newString = str_replace('test', 'egegeg', $string);
echo $newString;
// This is a egegeg
```

It works by passing in what you are looking for (test), what to replace it with (egegeg) and what string to search.

More details can be found on the PHP website - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Supryk what do you mean? Can you update your original answer with more context?

`str_replace` also looks at spaces. So if you want to replace only the word test when it has a space either side, then you can do `' test '` as the search string

Comment: @Supryk if it's got a capital letter, that is distinguishing enough.

Answer (score -1):

Search, find and replace.

```
$string = 'My awesome dude';
$replace = str_replace('awesome', 'bald', $string);

echo $replace;
```